# Space encoder for URL

Tags: c++, performance, x86

I’m starting to learn C++ by doing a lot of exercises. I want you to point me to **where/what** **improvements** I can do to make my code better.

The exercise:

> write a URLencode function that takes a string and searches for spaces and replace them with `%20`

My solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;
string  urlEncode(const string &a) {
    string b;
    for (auto& ch : a) {
        if (ch == ' ') {
            b.append("%20");
        }
        else {
            b.push_back(ch);
        }
    }
    return b;
}

int main() {

    assert(urlEncode("first second") == "first%20second");
    
    return 0;
}
```

I included [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag because most of the compiler nitty gritty optimization is done at that level, and I want to see the perspective of it from that side as well.

Comment: What x86 optimizations are you referring to? I see nothing in your code that is specific to x86.

Comment: things like caches, write buffer, ... etc

Comment: The performance tag might be better then.

Comment: It's quite rare that a C++ programmer targets just one instruction-set architecture - you might want to consider the [tag:embedded] tag if you are developing for an embedded system, and don't care about PDP-11, ARM, MIPS, RISC-V, etc.

Comment: April, several experienced Code Review members have made improvements to your question, and you have reverted them _without even leaving a comment_ to explain why.  That's called an "edit war", and is explicitly discouraged on Stack Exchange sites.  If you don't understand the improvements, or disagree with them, I recommend you visit [meta] to ask about asking.  Please help us to help you!

Comment: @TobySpeight I revered them because I wanted to keep track of the other questions listed below which you remove in your edit

Comment: Those questions can be found in your profile (accessed through your username as a link), and you can expect any reviewer interested in seeing what you have already learnt to follow that.  It's a good idea to link _related_ questions (e.g. if you improve code from an earlier question, or use a function you created earlier), but it's not a good way to document your developer journey.  Hope that helps!

Comment: @TobySpeight for you it is, for others it's not, as there are many people like me, looking for questions / answers / code review and instruction, using links will make it easy for them, otherwise it will be lost  in the track of other question that aren't related

Answer (score 7):

Firstly, it's great to see that you have thought about testing your code.  It's always a good idea to create as many automated tests as you can think up.  I might add a couple more tests, that ensure that the conversion is correct when the first and/or last character is a space (sometimes things that work in the middle can go slightly wrong at the ends).

If you're concerned about efficiency, then `for (auto& ch : a)` might not be what you want.  Because `ch` is a *reference*, then every access is indirect; `for (auto ch: a)` makes it a *value*, likely stored in a register.  An optimising compiler will probably transform this code for you, but why take the chance?  And why make it work harder, given that it's just as clear?

Comment: I was under the impression that `for (auto& ch : a)` would be faster as data won't have to be copied. Why is `for (auto ch : a)` faster here?

Comment: Because a reference is a level of indirection, similar to a pointer.  It's generally faster to copy a small value (such as `char`) than to access it via a reference (which in principle requires two reads each time it's used - good optimisation will reduce that).

Answer (score 6):

## General Observations

The code doesn't replace space with %20, it returns a second string with the correct value. While this does do the job of returning the proper string, it may waste memory. What did the original problem description really say? If you are writing code for embedded programming this may be a problem, since memory is limited on embedded devices.

Note optimization, the C++ compiler has 4 levels of optimization, O0 through O3, if you are writing code that manipulates hardware you may not be able to use all 4 levels of optimization. If you are not writing code that manipulates hardware O3 code provides the best level of optimization. The only way to really understand the optimization is to examine the intermediate assembly code that is generated.

## Avoid `using namespace std;`

If you are coding professionally you probably should get out of the habit of using the `using namespace std;` statement. The code will more clearly define where `cout` and other identifiers are coming from (`std::cin`, `std::cout`). As you start using namespaces in your code it is better to identify where each function comes from because there may be function name collisions from different namespaces. The identifier`cout` you may override within your own classes, and you may override the operator `<<` in your own classes as well. This [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) discusses this in more detail.

Comment: "The" C++ compiler?  Nothing in the C++ standard says there must be 4 optimisation levels to choose from.

Comment: dunno what compiler you're talking about, but for example `g++`  has 7: -O0 , -O1, -O2, -O3, -Ofast, -Os, -Og

Comment: What did the original problem description really say? - This is an entry level interview question, so nothing special. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/urlify-a-given-string-replace-spaces-with-%20/

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a pretty good exercise for learning C++, and your swing at it is well done. The most important accomplishment is that your code is *correct*; it gives the right answer, always, for all input. That’s no small feat. The hardest part of learning coding is getting things correct. Once you can get things correct, you can always refactor for efficiency.

Before I get into reviewing the code, I want to suggest that you take the time to learn a bit about unit testing in C++.

## Testing

Unfortunately, there’s no *standard* unit testing library, but there are a few nice ones out there you could use. A good choice for starting out might be [Catch2](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2). The easiest way to use Catch2 is to download [`catch_amalgamated.hpp`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/catchorg/Catch2/devel/extras/catch_amalgamated.hpp) and [`catch_amalgamated.cpp`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/catchorg/Catch2/devel/extras/catch_amalgamated.cpp), drop both of those files in the source directory of your project, and make sure you compile and link with `catch_amalgamated.cpp`.

With Catch2, this is how you’d test your code:

First you’d put your code in its own header and source files. In your case, you probably want `url_encode.hpp` and `url_encode.cpp`. The header will just have the declaration:

```
#ifndef INCLUDE_GUARD_change_this_to_whatever_you_want_thats_unique
#define INCLUDE_GUARD_change_this_to_whatever_you_want_thats_unique

#include <string>

std::string urlEncode(std::string const&);

#endif // include guard
```

The source file will have the definition:

```
#include "url_encode.hpp"

using namespace std;
string  urlEncode(const string &a) {
    string b;
    for (auto& ch : a) {
        if (ch == ' ') {
            b.append("%20");
        }
        else {
            b.push_back(ch);
        }
    }
    return b;
}
```

Next you’d create a test file. In your case, probably name it `url_encode.test.cpp`, make it look something like this:

```
#include "catch_amalgamated.hpp"

#include "url_encode.hpp"

TEST_CASE("urlEncode encodes correctly")
{
    CHECK(urlEncode("first second") == "first%20second");
}
```

(You’ll notice there’s no `main()`. Catch2 provides that for you.)

As you can see, the actual test is *exactly* what you wrote in your assert in `main()`, so you may be wondering what the point was. When everything works, it’s hard to see the benefit of a proper test library. So to illustrate, let’s temporarily break your code; let’s replace `b.push_back(ch)` with `b.push_back('x')`.

If you try to run your test program now, the test will fail and the assertion will fire… but all you’ll see is something like “`urlEncode("first second") == "first%20second" is not true`”. That’s good that it catches the problem… but it doesn’t really help much because it doesn’t tell you *why* the return value of `urlEncode()` doesn’t match.

Now try running the Catch2 version, and you will get output like this:

```
Randomness seeded to: 1305833654

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
a.out is a Catch2 v3.1.0 host application.
Run with -? for options

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
urlEncode encodes correctly
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
url_encode.test.cpp:5
...............................................................................

url_encode.test.cpp:7: FAILED:
  CHECK( urlEncode("first second") == "first%20second" )
with expansion:
  "xxxxx%20xxxxxx" == "first%20second"

===============================================================================
test cases: 1 | 1 failed
assertions: 1 | 1 failed
```

As you can see, it tells you:

1. Exactly which test failed (the test for “`urlEncode encodes correctly`”).
2. Exactly which file and line the failing test starts on (“`url_encode.test.cpp:5`”).
3. Exactly which file and line the failing assertion is on (“`url_encode.test.cpp:7`”).
4. What that assertion was (“`CHECK( urlEncode("first second") == "first%20second" )`”).
5. Exactly why it failed (“`"xxxxx%20xxxxxx" == "first%20second"`” wasn’t true).

You can see that all the non-space characters are `x`, which would give you a clue what the problem is (if you didn’t already know).

The real power of this comes when you add more tests:

```
#include "catch_amalgamated.hpp"

#include "url_encode.hpp"

TEST_CASE("urlEncode encodes correctly")
{
    CHECK(urlEncode("first second") == "first%20second");
    CHECK(urlEncode(" first second") == "%20first%20second");
    CHECK(urlEncode("first second ") == "first%20second%20");
    CHECK(urlEncode(" first second ") == "%20first%20second%20");
}

TEST_CASE("urlEncode handles empty strings")
{
    CHECK(urlEncode("") == "");
}

TEST_CASE("urlEncode input with no spaces")
{
    CHECK(urlEncode("a") == "a");
    CHECK(urlEncode("123") == "123");
    CHECK(urlEncode("a_longer-and_moreC0MPL3X_str") == "a_longer-and_moreC0MPL3X_str");
}

TEST_CASE("urlEncode input with only spaces")
{
    CHECK(urlEncode(" ") == "%20");
    CHECK(urlEncode("    ") == "%20%20%20%20");
}

// ... and so on...
```

With the broken function, the output is this:

```
Randomness seeded to: 4114723309

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
a.out is a Catch2 v3.1.0 host application.
Run with -? for options

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
urlEncode encodes correctly
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
url_encode.test.cpp:5
...............................................................................

url_encode.test.cpp:7: FAILED:
  CHECK( urlEncode("first second") == "first%20second" )
with expansion:
  "xxxxx%20xxxxxx" == "first%20second"

url_encode.test.cpp:8: FAILED:
  CHECK( urlEncode(" first second") == "%20first%20second" )
with expansion:
  "%20xxxxx%20xxxxxx" == "%20first%20second"

url_encode.test.cpp:9: FAILED:
  CHECK( urlEncode("first second ") == "first%20second%20" )
with expansion:
  "xxxxx%20xxxxxx%20" == "first%20second%20"

url_encode.test.cpp:10: FAILED:
  CHECK( urlEncode(" first second ") == "%20first%20second%20" )
with expansion:
  "%20xxxxx%20xxxxxx%20"
  ==
  "%20first%20second%20"

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
urlEncode input with no spaces
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
url_encode.test.cpp:18
...............................................................................

url_encode.test.cpp:20: FAILED:
  CHECK( urlEncode("a") == "a" )
with expansion:
  "x" == "a"

url_encode.test.cpp:21: FAILED:
  CHECK( urlEncode("123") == "123" )
with expansion:
  "xxx" == "123"

url_encode.test.cpp:22: FAILED:
  CHECK( urlEncode("a_longer-and_moreC0MPL3X_str") == "a_longer-and_moreC0MPL3X_str" )
with expansion:
  "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  ==
  "a_longer-and_moreC0MPL3X_str"

===============================================================================
test cases:  4 | 2 passed | 2 failed
assertions: 10 | 3 passed | 7 failed
```

Two test cases passed—the empty string and the one with only spaces, because neither has any non-space characters—and two failed—the one with only non-spaces, and the one with both spaces and non-spaces. This would be a strong clue that the problem is with non-space characters.

If you fix the `urlEncode()` back to what it should be, the output becomes:

```
Randomness seeded to: 1565700796
===============================================================================
All tests passed (10 assertions in 4 test cases)
```

Because, as I mentioned at the beginning, your code is correct. Now, thanks to testing, you *know*… for *sure*… that it’s correct. (And if you have any doubts, you can always add more tests.)

For the record, here are the commands I used to get the output above:

```sh
# Start in a new, empty directory.

# Create the source and header files, and fill them with the code:
edit url_encode.hpp
edit url_encode.cpp

# Create the test file, and fill it with the code:
edit url_encode.test.cpp

# Download the Catch2 stuff.
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/catchorg/Catch2/devel/extras/catch_amalgamated.hpp
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/catchorg/Catch2/devel/extras/catch_amalgamated.cpp

# Compile Catch2 (this will take a while, but you only need to do it once):
g++ -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -c catch_amalgamated.cpp

# --------------------------------------------------------------
# Everything above here only needs to be done once.
# Everything below here has to be done every time you make a change.
# --------------------------------------------------------------

# Each time I changed either the function or the tests:
g++ -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -c url_encode.cpp
g++ -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -c url_encode.test.cpp
g++ -pedantic -Wall -Wextra url_encode.test.o url_encode.o catch_amalgamated.o

# And then to run the tests:
./a.out
```

Of course, in practice I’d use a makefile or a build tool to automate all this. Not sure what you’re using or even what platform you’re on, but you can probably figure it all out.

## Design review

Okay, once you have testing down, fiddling with code becomes trivially easy. If you break anything, the tests will tell you right away, and you can always undo what you did.

### `std::string_view`

The first thing I would suggest is that instead of taking a `const std::string&` argument, you should use `std::string_view`.

Why? Because when you do `urlEncode("first second")`, that string literal is used to construct an actual `std::string`… which is often not cheap, and may involve memory allocations… and that `std::string` is then passed (by reference) to the function, and then… simply thrown away afterwards. What a waste.

If you used `std::string_view` instead, there are no string constructions, and no memory allocations. Instead, only a *view* of that string literal is passed to the function. Under the hood, only a pointer to the string data stored in the binary is passed along, which is super fast, and cheap.

And if you already have a `std::string` and want to pass that to the function, passing a view to that string is just as fast as passing a reference. So you lose nothing by switching to `std::string_view`, and gain a lot.

One warning though: `std::string_view` is sometimes called a **parameter-only type**. That means you can use it as a parameter to a function… *but you cannot return it*. (Well, that’s *technically* not true, but knowing when it’s safe is complex, expert-level stuff. Better to just not do it, for now.) So even if you change the parameter from `std::string const&` to `std::string_view`, you still need to return a `std::string`.

### Avoiding unnecessary allocations

The second thing I would suggest is reserving memory in the output string.

The way your code is written, it *theoretically* reallocates the entire string every time you add another character (or the `"%20"`). In other words, when transforming `"first second"`, what happens is:

1. The first character is `'f'`.

   - new memory in `b` is allocated to hold `"f"`
   - `'f'` is copied into it
2. The next character is `'i'`.

   - new memory in `b` is allocated to hold `"fi"`
   - the current content—`"f"`—is copied to the new memory
   - `'i'` is copied to the end of the new memory
   - the old memory is freed
3. The next character is `'r'`.

   - new memory in `b` is allocated to hold `"fir"`
   - the current content—`"fi"`—is copied to the new memory
   - `'r'` is copied to the end of the new memory
   - the old memory is freed
4. The next character is `'s'`.

   - new memory in `b` is allocated to hold `"firs"`
   - the current content—`"fir"`—is copied to the new memory
   - `'s'` is copied to the end of the new memory
   - the old memory is freed
5. The next character is `'t'`.

   - new memory in `b` is allocated to hold `"first"`
   - the current content—`"firs"`—is copied to the new memory
   - `'t'` is copied to the end of the new memory
   - the old memory is freed
6. The next character is a space, so `"%20"` will be appended.

   - new memory in `b` is allocated to hold `"first%20"`
   - the current content—`"first"`—is copied to the new memory
   - `"%20"` is copied to the end of the new memory
   - the old memory is freed

… and so on.

That’s 6 allocations, 5 de-allocations, and a ton of copies… and we haven’t even got to `"second"` yet.

(I’m exaggerating here, because no-one in their right mind would implement `std::string` to reallocate *this* much. Usually, each time `std::string` has to grow, it doesn’t necessarily grow by the minimum amount it needs to to fit the new data. In practice, it will grow by a factor of 2 or 1.5 (depending on the library). That means a lot fewer allocations… but it means wasted memory, so it’s a trade-off.)

Consider this strategy instead. First get the size of the string (`a.size()`). Then count the number of spaces in the string (`std::ranges::count(a, ' ')`). Multiply the number of spaces by the size of the replacement string minus one (why minus one? try to reason that out!). Then *reserve* that much memory in the output string.

So, something like this:

```
using namespace std::string_view_literals; // to get ""sv

constexpr auto replacement = "%20"sv;

auto b = std::string{};

auto const number_of_spaces = std::ranges::count(a, ' ');

b.reserve(
    a.size()
    + ((replacement.size() - 1) * number_of_spaces)
);

// rest of function is unchanged
```

Now all those `push_back()`s and `append()`s to `b` won’t need to allocate more memory, because you already pre-allocated all you’ll need.

### Don’t use raw loops

Using naked `for` loops—even range-`for` loops—is bad practice in modern C++. Instead, you should use algorithms.

*At the very least*, you should use `std::ranges::for_each()` (or `std::for_each()` before C++20). But even better would be to figure out which of [the standard algorithms](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) is the best fit.

For now, we’ll just stick with `std::ranges::for_each()`:

```
auto urlEncode(std::string const& a) -> std::string
{
    auto b = std::string{};

    std::ranges::for_each(a, [&b](auto&& ch)
    {
        if (ch == ' ') {
            b.append("%20");
        }
        else {
            b.push_back(ch);
        }
    });

    return b;
}
```

As you can see, there’s not really much difference—except you need to get used to the lambda syntax. But under the hood, there are actually a *lot* of improvements. The compiler can optimize the version with `std::ranges::for_each()` *much* easier than the naked-`for` loop version, for a number of reasons. (In practice, compilers are *so freaking good* at optimizing, that they’ll do the same job for both, at least for this simple case.) The real improvements will come when you start using more advanced algorithms—`for_each()` is the most absolute basic algorithm.

## Code review

```
using namespace std;
```

Never, ever, *ever* do this. It’s just not worth all the problems it causes.

```
string  urlEncode(const string &a) {
```

[In C++, the convention is to put the type modifier with the type](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#nl18-use-c-style-declarator-layout). C++ is all about the types. In other words:

- `const string &a`: this is C-style
- `const string& a`: this is C++-style
- `string const& a`: this is also C++-style, and has some benefits

```
    string b;
```

This is a style thing, so a lot of C++ coders will disagree (it’s not one of [the core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines), for example), but there is a trend in modern C++ toward replacing that old, C-style of defining variables to using the “(almost) always `auto`” style.

In the (A)AA style, you would write the above as:

```
    auto b = std::string{};
```

This has some more characters, but avoids a lot of problems with the old-school style.

You could also do:

```
    using namespace std::string_literals; // to get ""s

    auto b = ""s;
```

If you have a bunch of strings, this can save a *lot* of typing… but since you only have the single string, it’s probably not worth it.

Incidentally, `b` is not a great name for a variable. Neither is `a`. Instead of `a`, a better name might be `original`. A better name for `b` might be `transformed` or `encoded` or `result`… really anything other than just `b`.

So if I were to rewrite your code, I would start by transforming it to:

```
auto urlEncode(std::string const& original) -> std::string
{
    auto result = std::string{};

    for (auto ch : original)
    {
        if (ch == ' ') {
            result.append("%20");
        }
        else {
            result.push_back(ch);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Which, as you can see, isn’t really much change.

Next I might replace the `std::string const&` with `std::string_view`. That will give some performance gains.

Then I would probably replace the naked `for` loop with an algorithm. I’d probably just go with `std::ranges::for_each()`.

The only other thing I might change is putting the magic constants (`' '` and `"%20"`) into a named constants. Maybe like so:

```
auto urlEncode(std::string const& original) -> std::string
{
    constexpr auto unencoded_space = ' ';
    constexpr auto encoded_space = "%20";

    auto result = std::string{};

    for (auto ch : original)
    {
        if (ch == unencoded_space) {
            result.append(encoded_space);
        }
        else {
            result.push_back(ch);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Put altogether, the changes I would do might looks like:

```
auto urlEncode(std::string_view original) -> std::string
{
    using namespace std::string_view_literals;

    constexpr auto unencoded_space = ' ';
    constexpr auto encoded_space = "%20"sv;

    auto result = std::string{};

    result.reserve(
        original.size()
        + (
            (encoded_space.size() - 1)
            * std::ranges::count(original, unencoded_space)
        )
    );

    std::ranges::for_each(original, [&result, unencoded_space, encoded_space](auto&& ch)
    {
        if (ch == unencoded_space) {
            result.append(encoded_space);
        }
        else {
            result.push_back(ch);
        }
    });

    return result;
}
```

It’s quite a bit longer than yours mostly because of the reserve part in the middle, but I think that part is definitely worth it to avoid the repeated allocations.

If I were to go further, I might extract the part that calculates the encoded length out into its own function, because it could be quite useful. I might call it `urlEncodedLength()`. If I did that, then `urlEncode()` would simplify to:

```
auto urlEncode(std::string_view original) -> std::string
{
    auto result = std::string{};
    result.reserve(urlEncodedLength(original));

    std::ranges::for_each(original, [&result](auto&& ch)
    {
        if (ch == unencoded_space) {
            result.append(encoded_space);
        }
        else {
            result.push_back(ch);
        }
    });

    return result;
}
```

Which is pretty much exactly your function plus one extra line to do the reserve.

## Future directions

### URL-encode all the things!

URL-encoding is more than just turning spaces into `"%20"`. [There are more than a dozen characters that have to be transformed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Reserved_characters). I would suggest expanding `urlEncode()` to handle all of them.

The way I would suggest doing it is to *first* write the tests:

```
TEST_CASE("Reserved characters are transformed")
{
    CHECK(urlEncode(" ") == "%20");
    CHECK(urlEncode("!") == "%21");
    CHECK(urlEncode("#") == "%23");
    // ... and so on...
}

TEST_CASE("Only the reserved characters get transformed")
{
    CHECK(urlEncode("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding")
        == "https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FPercent-encoding")
    // ... other checks with a mix of reserved/non-reserved characters...
}
```

They will fail, of course. That’s good; they should; they shouldn’t pass when you haven’t implemented the functionality yet.

Now you can start modifying `urlEncode()`.

As a first pass, you can do a bunch of `if` tests:

```
if (ch == unencoded_space) {
    result.append(encoded_space);
}
else if (ch == unencoded_bang) {
    result.append(encoded_bang);
}
else if (ch == unencoded_pound) {
    result.append(encoded_pound);
}
// ... and so on...
else {
    result.push_back(ch);
}
```

Then, maybe try simplifying with a `switch` statement.

Then, I suggest getting really adventurous, and creating a map of reserved characters and encoded transformations. Something like:

```
auto const encoding_map = std::unordered_map<char, std::string>{
    {' ', "%20"},
    {'!', "%21"},
    // ... and so on...
};
```

Then use *that* to do the encoding, rather than a bunch of `if`s or even a `switch`. (You can use the same map to do the length calculation, too.)

The neat thing about using a map, rather than a bunch of `if`s, is that it’s *really* easy to change the encoding, or add new transforms. In fact, with a mapping, you could theoretically copy almost the entirety of `urlEncode()` to a new function that does C-string escaping (like transforming `'"'` to `'\"'`) or shell-escaping or whatever… all you’d need to do is change the map data to reflect the new encoding.

And *then*, try replacing the very expensive unordered map with a *highly* efficient compile-time array of pairs (or tuples). Once you get to this point, you will pretty much be writing the kind of code I’d expect to see from a professional-class C++ coder.

Getting to this point won’t be *easy*, but if you take small steps, you should manage it. Just remember to always check your work with the tests, to see if you’ve improved things, or introduced bugs.

And you could go even further, to *beyond* professional-class C++ coder, by writing versions of `urlEncode()` that work on arbitrary ranges (not just strings and string views), and only reserving when you have at least forward ranges. You could maybe even make a coroutine generator version. *That* level of C++ mastery will take a *long* time to work up to.

I’d say don’t worry about going *that* far just yet, and don’t try to bite off too much challenge too quickly. Just take small steps, incremental improvements. You’ve already got really good code, which suggests you have really good coding instincts. In other words, you’re off to an excellent start. Build up those coding muscles slowly, bit-by-bit. Make small improvements, getting a deep understanding of what you’re improving and *why* it’s an improvement, each step. That will build you up toward being not just a *good* C++ coder, but one of the best.

Comment: The allocation part is debatable in the particular case due to the small string optimization. I would guess the "first second" is stored on stack. Nevertheless, It is a good point in general.